# How to remove or delete Android app from Admob?

Tags: android, admob

I am new to advertising in Android.
I have linked my admob app to a random app on play store.
Now i want to remove that app so i was wondering. Is there a way to remove it from my Ad Mob account. Cause its not actually my app so i don't want to see it in my Ad Mob account home tab

I tried to find something on Google but had no luck.I found a depressing thing in **Q.6** in  [FAQ](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/faq/3108470#3316383) section of Admob. According to which they said

**At this time, you cannot rename or delete an app. Instead, create a new app and move the relevant ad units from under the 'Unknown app' to the new app.**

So i am wondering. Is there really no way i can delete the specific app from my admob account. if so then will this feature be available in future?

Comment: Google said it to you... Maybe try to contact them and ask for help, but I guess you won't have any luck.

Answer (score 19):

At least, you can hide it

- click "Manage your apps"

[image: how to hide your admob apps]

- select and hide your apps

[image: select and hide]

Answer (score 8):

Google keeps a track of all apps. Be aware if your developer console is shut for any reason, then to avoid that developer to create new account and apps to google play, then if you link your new app to the old admob which contains your history of apps, then google will catch the account and shut it down. Try another app monetizing network. admob is now rigged by google.

Answer (score 6):

Not at this time, as the Admob [FAQ](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/faq/3108470#3316383) says.
But you can now hide those apps that you no longer want to see.

Comment: One year later and it is still not possible. That's really bad.

Comment: @mars3142 seems it's still very difficult task for Google engineers :D

Comment: Or they are working on higher priority things. This is hardly a killer issue.

Comment: What exactly happens when you click the +Monetize button for an app?

Comment: Four years later and it is still not possible. That's extremely bad.

Comment: It still the same in 2019

Comment: It's probably more like they don't want you to delete apps from your account. In case one app is or becomes fraudulent they have you right by the guts

Comment: same in 2022.  0% customer service. Human support non-existent . Boat driven techno jargon . community help yields no fruitful outcome . continue to send ad-restriction messages years  after google play account disabled. privacy violation not removed even though they know you can't fix it because the app has been removed from stores and admob units deleted. Total deviation from common-sense!

Comment: Google has not paid any attention to Admob, Adsense and Play Console. They have poor customer service and horrible limitations. Almost 10 years have passed, still we are stuck

Comment: @ruX Yeah, true. We can request them to hire us, we will fix this and leave the next day :P

Answer (score 4):

You can't delete the app but you can rename it and re-use that spot.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of uploading another app insert the new advertising sources into the one you want to remove (delete the advertising sources that already exists), then you "re-link" with the app form google play sotre, wait a few hours, you wont have an app unused in admob template.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible. 
1. Goto Manage settings for an app.
2. On the settings page press edit
3. At the bottom you'll see "Delete Site" button to delete the application

Please note this action is non-reversible. So if you delete the site no ad impression would be sent to your app.

### Im still using older admob, this option is available in older admob.

Comment: Where's the manage settings for the app? I can't find it in Monetize app screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least get rid of an ad unit for an app you want deleted from AdMob, in my case a paid game app that no longer exists (it's hard to get android game players to even pay .99 up front nowadays). It appears you still can't delete the app itself from the 'All Apps' listing, which is irritating, although you can 'Hide' it.

Click your 'Monetize' tab. Click the target app from the left app list under 'All Apps'. Now clicking the 'Settings' tab doesn't show anything at all except a box to click for increasing the security of the app, at least for me. Instead, click the 'Ad Units' tab, if it's not already the active 
tab. Click the box to the left of your ad unit to select it. That will light the 'Move' and Archive' buttons, previously greyed out. Click the 'Archive' button. Now you will get a warning popup saying archiving is permanent. Click the 'Archive' button on the bottom of the warning popup. Now the ad unit won't show.

Answer (score 0):

From `All Apps` > `Apps to confirm` > `Requires Setup`

Find the accidentally added app and click on `Not my app`

[image]